# Are inter-racial marriages frowned upon?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Apparently, [marriage is allowed](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Marriage) in *Elder Scrolls: Skyrim*.

For example, as a Human, if I wanted to show my love for an Argonian or Khajit, and they were up for it, would I be shunned or treated differently by NPCs?

Comment: Yet another great title for everyone to gawk at when it shows up in 'hot questions'...

Comment: This is an excellent question and I'm curious for the answer. Supposedly in Skyrim, every single NPC has a direct opinion of you...interracial marriage should definitely play a role in that.

Comment: Are the only a separate race, or are they a separate species?  Shouldn't this be about inter-species marriages?

Comment: @Zoredache Going by terminology used in the past games and on the wiki, they are referred to as races, not species. I had originally titled it as inter-species. I don't know if there's a specific reason why.

Comment: Most of the races are offshoots of elves. I believe out of the playable races, only the Khajiit and argonians aren't related to elves.

Comment: @Arkive - I don't believe the human subraces are descended from elves.

Comment: @Raven it seems you're correct. The main races are grouped Man, Mer, and Beast. http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Races

Comment: As for why "race", it's just fantasy-genre convention to use "race" when what is actually meant is "species". Blame the 1978 printing of D&D. In TES there are both different species and different races in the species, but they roll it all together under "race".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Skyrim's idea of romance is pretty tame compared to other RPG franchises (like *Dragon Age* and *Mass Effect* from BioWare). For the most part, who you marry is completely irrelevant, and nobody will comment about it: Skyrim is a very forward-thinking kind of place.

The official guide confirms this, even highlighting the lack of racial effects on marriage as a bonus.

So go and marry that Argonian, we won't judge (not that there's anything wrong with it).

Comment: No, not at all!

Comment: [Not when you're a werewolf](http://imgur.com/a/HOUjd).